# My JavaScript form validation function is called two times

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to print the value from the form when a user submits the function but a blank value is returned.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var login = new function()
{
    var name = null ;

    this.validation = function()
    {
        this.name = document.getElementById("Username").value;
        console.log(this.name); 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.name;
    };
};
```

And my HTML form as :

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Login with javascript</h1>
        <p class="lead">Please Enter Following Details</p>
        <h1 id="demo"></h1>
        <form name="form" onSubmit="return login.validation();" action="#" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="Username" placeholder="Please Enter your Username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Please enter your Password">
          </div>          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Re-Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Re-Password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>          
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>

      </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    <script href="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </body>
```

Why does the value not get into html `<p>` tag.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you've provided. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: Side note: You don't need `type="submit"` on `button` elements. `submit` is the default type for them.

Comment: Thanks, i did changes but nothing happens still not getting value into HTML page.

Comment: Why something should be shown in <p> tag ? #demo is h1

Comment: That was a *side note*. We still need the MCVE to solve the actual problem.

Comment: Here's is your code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/p2y4j28x/1/
I've changed how the submit works but it should do the same.....and it works fine. If anything, you should add `return false` to the validation function so that the form doesn't submit instantly.

Comment: Thanks, it worked you really saved my lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Your code simply works. But since the function executes on submitting the form, the username gets logged in the console fast before the page refreshed with submitted data. You can confirm this and test it by adding `event.preventDefault();` to the function to prevent submitting the form so the page would stay visible with the console.

```
<script>
    var login = new function()
    {
    var name = null ;

    this.validation = function()
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.name = document.getElementById("Username").value;
        console.log(this.name); 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.name;
        };
    };
</script>
```

If that's not what you're looking for, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

We the javascript validation failed you need to return false. If you don't it will proceed your form further. Thanks

```
var login = new function()
        {
            var name = null ;

            this.validation = function()
            {
                this.name = document.getElementById("Username").value;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.name;
                return false;
            };
        };
```